# Tag an already tokenised string with spaCy

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

To make a comparable study, I am working with data that has already been tokenised (not with spacy). I need to use these tokens as input to ensure that I work with the same data across the board. I wish to feed these tokens into spaCy's tagger, but the following fails:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['tokenizer', 'parser', 'ner', 'textcat'])
sent = ['I', 'like', 'yellow', 'bananas']

doc = nlp(sent)

for i in doc:
    print(i)
```

with the following trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/bmvroy/.PyCharm2018.2/config/scratches/scratch_6.py", line 6, in <module>
    doc = nlp(sent)
  File "C:\Users\bmvroy\venv\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 346, in __call__
    doc = self.make_doc(text)
  File "C:\Users\bmvroy\venv\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 378, in make_doc
    return self.tokenizer(text)
TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got list)
```

First of all, I'm not sure why spaCy tries to tokenize the input as I disabled the tokenizer in the `load()` statement. Second, evidently this is not the way to go.

I am looking for a way to feed the tagger a list of tokens. Is that possible with spaCy?

---

I tried the solution provided by @aab combined with info from [the documentation](https://spacy.io/api/tagger#call) but to no avail:

```
from spacy.tokens import Doc
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.pipeline import Tagger

nlp = English()
tagger = Tagger(nlp.vocab)

words = ['Listen', 'up', '.']
spaces = [True, False, False]

doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=words, spaces=spaces)
processed = tagger(doc)
print(processed)
```

This code didn't run, and gave the following error:

```
    processed = tagger(doc)
  File "pipeline.pyx", line 426, in spacy.pipeline.Tagger.__call__
  File "pipeline.pyx", line 438, in spacy.pipeline.Tagger.predict
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'tok2vec'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the alternate way of constructing a document directly using the `Doc` class. Here's the example from their docs (https://spacy.io/api/doc):

```
from spacy.tokens import Doc
doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=[u'hello', u'world', u'!'], spaces=[True, False, False])
```

The `spaces` argument (whether each token is followed by a space) is optional.

Then you can run the components you need, so the whole thing would look like:

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc

nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=[u'hello', u'world', u'!'], spaces=[True, False, False])

nlp.tagger(doc)
nlp.parser(doc)

for t in doc:
    print(t.text, t.pos_, t.tag_, t.dep_, t.head)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Unfortunately, this did not work for me. I edited my OP to show you the code that I tried and the error that it returned. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the rest of that code, it's not the usual way to load spacy. I'll edit my example with a bit more code.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got the example code from the documentation but perhaps I implemented it wrongly. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @BramVanroy The initial example wasn't working because you only created the English language class (`nlp = English()`), didn't load any statistical model and then created an empty tagger that doesn't have any data available and whose weights aren't initialized. Without the model weights, the tagger won't be able to assign any tags to your `Doc`. spaCy should probably fail more gracefully here, though!

Comment: One small addition to the code above: Instead of using `nlp.tagger` and `nlp.parser`, you can also get the pipeline components using the [`nlp.get_pipe`](https://spacy.io/api/language#get_pipe) method, e.g. `tagger = nlp.get_pipe('tagger')`. This is a bit more explicit, because you're telling spaCy that you want the [pipeline component](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines) with *this exact name* that's present in the model pipeline. The result is the same as going via `nlp.tagger`, but I usually recommend the more explicit syntax.

Comment: @InesMontani Thank you for your reply! You can always add an additional answer with my code, fixed (i.e. with the additional step of loading the model). You don't have to, but it would be nice to see the alternative approach!